# Evolving curves by Alexander Polden

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, flows

I am writing a piece on curve shortening flow and lots of my sources have referenced Alexander Polden's honours thesis 'Evolving Curves' from the Australian National University. I have tried to find this paper to no avail, even through ANU's thesis catalogue [here](http://anulib.anu.edu.au/collections/theses) which returns nothing. I was wondering whether anyone could provide me access to this paper (I don't know if there are any copyright issues with such theses) - I would very much like to read it and most likely cite it. Thanks.

Comment: The MSI (ANU maths department) used to keep honour's theses on their intranet. If you know someone at MSI, they may be able to access it. Otherwise, you could probably request it directly from the department but I have no idea whether they'll give it to you or not though. Worth trying at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly what you are seeking, but apparently a 21-page piece of it. In the paper by Gerhard Huisken and Alexander Polden, "Geometric evolution equations for hypersurfaces." *Calculus of Variations and Geometric Evolution Problems*. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1999. 45-84, they say:

---

[image: Polden]

---

That last section is about 21 pages long.

- [PDF download](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:152741/component/escidoc:152740/332727.pdf): Huisken-Polden paper.
- [Springer link to collection](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540659778): *Calculus of Variations and Geometric Evolution Problems*.